# TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor (python social distancing detection append())

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, centroid

I have a project to detect distance between people. the project runs smoothly when the centroid and the plotting line is in the center of the people. But, i want to move the centroid and the plotting line to the feet of the people, I have successfully move the centroid but the plotting line is not move along the centroid. here's the code:

utils.py (def distancing)

```py
def distancing(people_coords, img, dist_thres_lim=(200,250)):
    # Plot lines connecting people
    already_red = dict() # dictionary to store if a plotted rectangle has already been labelled as high risk
    centers = []
    for i in people_coords:
        centers.append(((int(i[0])+int(i[2]))//2, (int(max(i[3]), (i[1])))))
    
    for j in centers:
        already_red[j] = 0
    x_combs = list(itertools.combinations(people_coords,2))
    
    radius = 10
    thickness = 5
    for x in x_combs:
        xyxy1, xyxy2 = x[0],x[1]
        cntr1 = ((int(xyxy1[2])+int(xyxy1[0]))//2,(int(xyxy1[3])+int(xyxy1[1]))//2)
        cntr2 = ((int(xyxy2[2])+int(xyxy2[0]))//2,(int(xyxy2[3])+int(xyxy2[1]))//2)
        dist = ((cntr2[0]-cntr1[0])**2 + (cntr2[1]-cntr1[1])**2)**0.5
```

the problem is in **people_coords**(looping) xy coordinate. I have tried to change the code with (int(max(i[3]), (i[1]))))) but when I runs it, I get an error (TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor). what should I do to move the plotting line along with the centroid?

here is the centroid code

```py
def plot_dots_on_people(x, img):
    # Plotting centers of people with green dot.
    thickness = -1;
    color = [0, 255, 0] # green
    center = ((int(x[0])+int(x[2]))//2, (int(max(x[3], x[1]))))

    radius = 10
    cv2.circle(img, center, radius, color, thickness)
```

I hope someone can help me, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest printing the value of people_coords and running people_coords.size() . The error comes from iterating over a tensor that has a size of `torch.Size([])`. An example tensor with that size is like `torch.tensor(5)`.

One way to solve this error is to make sure people_coords is the value you expect it to be by using the debugging steps I illustrated above or you can use unsqueeze to turn torch.tensor(x) to torch.tensor([x]) and thus make it iterable.

Sarthak Jain